# jquery ajax form submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, post, submit

Is this code correct? I'm trying to submit it and also I would like on submit if text area would be empty again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
        // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
        var fid = $(".messag").attr("id");
        var val = $("#mess_ar").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send_message.php",
            data: "fid="+ fid +"&val="+ val,
            success: function(){
                    $("#mess_ar").
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
}):
</script>
```

I'm trying to upload this:

```
<form id="submit" method="POST">
<textarea name="mess_cont" id="mess_ar" autofocus="autofocus" cols="70" rows="5">      </textarea>
<button id="mess_but" type="submit">Send</button>
</form>
```

Thankx...

Comment: you probably need to add a parameter into your event catching function like so `$("form#submit").submit(function(e) {` you can then use `e.preventDefault()` to stop the default action, submit, from happening

Comment: @ianbarker return false; is already being used at the end.

Comment: Nothing in the HTML you posted has class "messag", so that line that tries to set "fid" will set it to `null`. Also the "success" function is clearly incomplete; do you want to just cal `.val('')` to clear the textarea?

Comment: @TJ. I missed that, however I think `preventDefault()` is the preferred method when using jQuery

Comment: .messag is element out of this form

Comment: @ianbarker We're in agreement, it's in general the better method because you can place it right at the beginning of the event handler and if an error occurs afterwards the default action is still not executed. This is where return false fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
​$(function(){
    $("form#submit").submit(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fid = $(".messag").attr("id");
        var val = $("#mess_ar").val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send_message.php",
            data: "fid="+ fid +"&val="+ val,
            success: function(){
                $("#mess_ar").val("");
            }
        });
    });
});​
```

Use

```
$("#submit").on('submit', function(e){...});
```

instead of

```
$("#submit").submit(function(e){...});
```

if you are using latest version of jquery.

Comment: why is it on submit reloading whole page?

Comment: Did you added e.preventDefault(), please take a look at this http://jsfiddle.net/GkCbD/2/

Answer (score 3):

Looks good. To empty the textarea use the following in the ajax success callback:

```
$("#mess_ar").val('');
```

Answer (score 2):

What are you actually looking for? Does it return the data in response too? Add the functions to track your the error case too. Make something like

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("form#submit").submit(function() {
       // we want to store the values from the form input box, then send via ajax below
       var fid = $(".messag").attr("id");
       var val = $("#mess_ar").val();
       $.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: "send_message.php",
          data: "fid="+ fid +"&val="+ val,
          success: function(incoming_data){
             // ALERT incoming data if coming
             $("#mess_ar").text(""); // DO YOUR JOB CONTINUOU
          },
          error: function() { 
             alert("BROKEN REQUEST.");
          }
       });
       return false;
   });

});
</script>
```

Else, seems all fine.

Comment: and I should be able to receive them in my php file line normal $_POST['']?

Comment: yeah, as you are passing parameters from your ajax ` data: "fid="+ fid +"&val="+ val` so they can be accessed in php by `$_POST['fid']` and '$_POST['val']'. However, error comes in the form of client side error object. So, if you want to pass to php server side, you need to make another can in which you pass your Error Object!