# how to stop Math.random to NOT iterate with each .click()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am learning jQuery/js and working on the 'hot or cold' exercise that appears to be a popular starting point.

However when submitting the user's input, `.click()` appears to cause `Math.random` to generate a new number, thus creating a new number each time the user submits a guess. The desired outcome is that the generated number remains the same.

From what I can tell, my code *LOOKS* correct. Could someone explain my error?

HTML

```
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>

<button>
      play?
   </button>

<div class="show">
    </div>

   <form>
    <input type="text" name="inputform" id="textbox" 
    autocomplete="off" value="">
    <input type="submit" id="txtbutton" class="txtbutton" value="Submit">
   </form>

  <div class="showMore">
  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var randomNum = Math.floor((Math.random()*100)+1);

    $('div').text(randomNum);

    var ui = $('#textbox');

    $('.txtbutton').click(function(){
        var clearGuess = function() {
            $("#userGuess").val("").focus();
        };
        var x = ui.val();
    });
});
```

Comment: What is *your error*? From my perspective, it looks fine!?!

Comment: There is code that you are not showing... show all relevant code, please.

Comment: Does the page reload when a guess is submitted?

Comment: @d'alar'cop edited to show all .js & .html

Comment: @Blazemonger I can only assume that it is reloading on submit. but I do not know how to stop this if it is the issues. I have tried 'event.preventDefault();' but this does not seem to have the desired outcome.

Comment: If that sometimes not works, try `return false` at the end.

Comment: your submitting your form, but not using ajax.form to capture this, in order to submit via ajax http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9789082/jquery-ajax-form-submit

Comment: @davethecoder he doesn't actually need a form in the first place for what he's doing.

Comment: @davethecoder since we have yet to reach ajax in the course (it is a future topic), I would assume that this can be accomplished without the use of ajax. is that possible?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum   :-)   yeah i know, but it is there, so I am assuming that this is early test of what will eventually be a submitting of data

Comment: @72Monkeys   remove your form tags then,  you have a form, this form is posted, the page is refreshed, your code is then generating a new random.   remove the form, add a normal button, capture the click event

Comment: @72Monkeys $('.txtbutton').click(function(){   does not pick up the click event on your button, because the event is not a click, the event is a form submit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Whenever you click that button - the form submits which causes a page reload.

In order to prevent submitting all forms you can:

```
$("form").submit(function(){
     return false;
});
```

Which should fix your problem.

Good luck, and enjoy coding JavaScript.